# How do I target the :active pseudo-class in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css

I am looking to target the :active psuedo class in jQuery. Essentially when the active state is activated, I would like a simple animation to occur. Is there a way to target ":active" just as there is in CSS?

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to do this in JavaScript, but you can bind the animation to events that would cause an element to be considered `:active`, i.e. `click`:

```
$(element).on('click', function () { /* anmiation * / });
```

Animations are also possible via CSS and you would be able to use `:active` directly with those.

Comment: +1 But the equivalent to `:active` in terms of events on an element would be `mousedown`.

Comment: @AustinBrunkhorst not necessarily; you can trigger active state by focusing and hitting spacebar sometimes, although `'click mousedown'` may be more appropriate

Answer (score 0):

for inputs i think this will be what you want

```
$(":input").focusin(function() { .... });
$(":input").focusout(function() { .... })
```